# Rows As Stacked Bar Plot Using ggplot2 In R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, stacked-chart

I am just getting started with `ggplot2()` (data visualization) in `R`. The data I have has different workloads in row format. Each of these column has four different parameters that I want to plot as stacked bar plot, preferably using `ggplot2()`.

**Reproducible Data**

```
Workload P1   P2   P3   P4
W1       0.3  0.2  0.4  0.1
W2       0.5  0.1  0.3  0.1
W3       0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1
W4       0.3  0.2  0.5  0.1
```

I want to plot `Workload` as `x-axis` and then `P1`, `P2`, `P3` and `P4` will be stacked for each of the workload on `y-axis`.

I tried many things, but I am getting tangled with `ggplot2()` parameters and arguments. If anyone can suggest how I can do this, it will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to put your data into a long format using `melt` or `gather`. Can't really help you with that unless you share sample data.

Comment: @Gregor - I have edited the question. Accidentally pressed enter before completing the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to the "superior" long format (here I use `tidyr::gather`), then map your columns to aesthetics, with a column geom with stacked position (bar is a special case which counts number of observations).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
Workload P1   P2   P3   P4
W1       0.3  0.2  0.4  0.1
W2       0.5  0.1  0.3  0.1
W3       0.2  0.3  0.4  0.1
W4       0.3  0.2  0.5  0.1", header = TRUE)


df_long <- df %>% 
  gather(P, value, P1:P4)

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Workload, y = value, fill = P)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_stack())
```

[image]

Comment: .@JackBrookes - Thanks, it worked. I am trying to change the colors to gray scale and I added `scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)` to your code. This gives to different gray levels for each block of stacked column. Is it possible to change the gray scale to something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knsiN.png).

Comment: Ggplot doesn't support textured fills, but you can have any color you like