# How to make a stacked bar plot in R with the data from a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table that looks as follows:

| family | max | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OG0000000 | 1336 | 348.23423423423424 |
| OG0000001 | 152 | 66.31531531531532 |
| OG0000002 | 104 | 33.85585585585586 |
| OG0000003 | 133 | 32.990990990990994 |
| OG0000004 | 118 | 31.135135135135137 |
| OG0000005 | 79 | 30.83783783783784 |
| OG0000006 | 123 | 30.153153153153152 |
| OG0000007 | 131 | 29.81081081081081 |
| OG0000008 | 129 | 29.684684684684683 |
| OG0000009 | 93 | 29.405405405405407 |
| OG0000011 | 169 | 28.35135135135135 |
| OG0000012 | 73 | 27.56756756756757 |
| OG0000013 | 113 | 27.504504504504503 |
| OG0000014 | 87 | 24.72972972972973 |
| OG0000015 | 106 | 24.675675675675677 |
| OG0000017 | 131 | 23.306306306306308 |
| OG0000018 | 80 | 22.81081081081081 |
| OG0000020 | 234 | 21.324324324324323 |
| OG0000024 | 89 | 20.89189189189189 |

I want to make a bar plot where each bar takes the data in column one('family') as the label and stacks the data in columns two and three for each bar. Say the datapoints from column two make up the primary data show in the bars and the data from the third column is overlaid over it.

I am trying to do this in ggplot.

I have tried the following approach (as taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380229/rows-as-stacked-bar-plot-using-ggplot2-in-r)):

```r
df_long <- df2 %>% gather(family,counts, 2:3) # here df is the above table as a dataframe
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = family, y = counts, fill = family)) + geom_col(position = position_stack())
```

This gives an output in the following design, and this is really not what I want.

[image: The image that this code produced]

Not sure if the code in the linked post is outdated or if I am doing something wrong.

I see some random webpages here [(for example)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_bar_charts.htm) and there showing syntax like this `barplot(Values, main = "total revenue", names.arg = months, xlab = "month", ylab = "revenue", col = colors)` to make bar plots but here the `values` object needs to be a vector (which I am not sure I how to pass two sets of data to.)

Searching around on google, it seems stacked bar plots are a bit hard to track down. Unfortunately I am not the most familiar with the `grammar of graphics`, anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stack the max and mean together for each family, then you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-family) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = family, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

**Output**

[image]

Another option (rather than mixing stats) would be to use `facet_wrap`, so that you mean in one graph and max in another:

```
df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-family) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = family, y = value)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1400, 200),
                     limits = c(0, 1400)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ name, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks cool! but I think it will be easier to communicate the data if each `family` gets its own bar and within each bar the mean and the max data points get shown, so one bar per row or vice versa. Is that possible ?

Comment: @RijanDhakal I just added another option. Honestly, if you are wanting to show the comparison between families, then I wouldn't stack them. I would just facet to show the comparison for mean and max separately. Does this work better? Or are you thinking something different?

Comment: Faceting is good too. Any way to force similar vertical scaling across facets? I think having the same vertical scales in both the graphs might make the comparison a little easier visually (in the above graph 300 and 1000 look somewhat similar) but other than that faceting is great too.

Comment: @RijanDhakal I updated my answer to stack the max and mean together by family (at the top now), and I updated the second figure with faceting so that the y-axis is the same for each.